# Download a picture via a URL

Tags: javascript

This is the URL: http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kij/gGE/KijgGEgrT.png

This is my page code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Some title</title>
<script>
function DownloadUrl(url)
{
// Download that url
}
</script>
<body>
<button onclick="DownloadUrl('http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kij/gGE/KijgGEgrT.png')">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My page and the picture URL page are different.

Comment: download attibute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: @ user3378165 Thanks for reply ,please read the title

Comment: @techno01 I'm not sure what you mean, you still "Download a pictrue from a giving url"

Comment: Means clicking on the button downloads the image to the user's computer.

Comment: @techno01 In my solution, clicking on the link will download the image to the user's computer?! Do you specifically need a button and not a link?

Comment: @ user3378165 exactly what @ epascarello saying

Comment: is there anything new

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for downloading a file from a url, you can use a `<a>` tag and add a `download` html attribute as below:

```
<html>
<head><title>Some title</title>
<body>
<a href="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kij/gGE/KijgGEgrT.png" download> Download here! </a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the most common solution.

You can also do it this way:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kij/gGE/KijgGEgrT.png">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I said above "PS : my page and picture url page are diffirent" ,means I want to download it from another website

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download) and see how the html `download` attribute is exactly what you need.

Comment: your mothode will work only for one url what if I want to download like 5 .I want something dynamic and i think it done by some javascript functions

Comment: You didn't mention that... I answered your question, you can post another question.

Comment: dont get me wrong but I think I mention it in the PS.never mind ,now you understand what I want to do can you post the solution ,please

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
<script>
function DownloadUrl(url)
{
 window.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ Shobhit WaliaThanks for replying,your code open the url in new tab ,but   i want to download that url

Comment: I think you need to write server side code for Download the image <form method="get" action="file.doc">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>